# How to pass user defined payload to IoTHub Device Provisioning Service when using IoTEdge

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

It seems that a year ago we got a feature of passing extra payload to dps.
[Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service—June 2019 update](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/updates/azure-iot-hub-device-provisioning-service-june-2019-update/)

How do I do this when using the IoTedge? The /etc/iotedge/config.yaml, does not seem to have a field for this, nor does the documentation have any info on this not being supported.

Comment: Did you look at [How to transfer a payload between device and DPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-send-additional-data)

Comment: Yes I did. The "blog post" however seems to be for the case when you are *not* using the iotedge, but the sole iothub. To format the question more clearly where should I define the payload, since in the case of IoTEdge it seems that the edge runtime is the one that makes the connection, based on the configuration file I mentioned, not me via the SDK.