# Custom DPS Enrollment payload on IoT Edge

Tags: azure-iot-edge

We are using IoT Edge with DPS and we would need to provide additional information at provisioning time to provision the device in the correct IoT Hub and with specific twin information. We noticed DPS offers a [solution for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-send-additional-data) where we can pass a json payload then surfaced in the custom allocation function. However, all documentation point to implementation using the DPS provisioning SDK.
[Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62522733/how-to-pass-user-defined-payload-to-iothub-device-provisioning-service-when-usin) where left without satisfying answers :(.

Is there a way to provide this additional information for DPS event? For example in the config.yaml?

Best regards & thanks for the help!

Mik

Answer (score 0):

IoT Edge isn't currently supporting a custom payload that can be passed to DPS. Suggest that a new feedback request is added here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/907045-azure-iot-edge